# Atoi of a long string error

Tags: c

I have this code:

char kbits[k];
long int bits;

The kbits string is always filled with '1', for example:

If k = 5,
kbits = "11111"

If k = 9,
kbits = "111111111"

To do this I use this code:

for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
     kbits[i] = '1';

And then I run:

bits = atoi(kbits);

So I have the integer of kbits, for example, if kbits = "1111", bits = 1111;

For k <= 10, it runs perfectly fine.

For k > 10 it puts a 7 in last position of kbits (for example, if k = 11, kbits = 11111111117) and bits = 2147483647 (this value is for any value of k, I think it is random?)

Comment: Your input number is too large.

Comment: show complete code please

Comment: 5 months is long enough to read the post formatting instructions. Please do that _now_, then edit your question.

Comment: I agree with @EdS , the largest 'safe' input is 9999999 which is 7 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atoi` interprets its input as a decimal number, not a binary number. Your longer string is causing the value to overflow, in which case the return value of `atoi` is undefined (although returning `INT_MAX` is common, which is equal to the value you're seeing).

To interpret the input as a binary number you can use `strtol` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    char line[256];

    while (printf("\nInput: "),
           fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    {
        // skip initial whitespace and break if input is nothing but whitespace
        char *p = line;
        while (isspace(*p)) ++p;
        if (*p == '\0') break;

        // interpret input as a binary number    
        long n = strtol(line, &p, 2);

        if (p == line)
            printf("** Can't convert any characters. **\n");
        else if (n == LONG_MAX || n == LONG_MIN)
            printf("** Range error **\n");
        else
            printf("Value: %ld\n", n); // prints value in decimal

        while (isspace(*p)) ++p; // skip whitespace after the value
        if (*p != '\0')
            printf("** Excess characters in input **\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, the return value is undefined in this case, but `INT_MAX` is a common result in practice.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're absolutely correct. I'm going to edit the post to say so. (And I can't believe I made the "it's"/"its" mistake! Thanks for spotting that.)

Answer (score 2):

Your input is too large for the return type.  Per the docs:

> If the converted value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.

An int is a signed type of *at least* 16-bits.  On your platform it may be 32-bits and, in that case, its max value is 2^31-1.  Too small for your input of ~11 billion.  Use `strtol`, which returns a `long int`, instead.

Also, make sure you're terminating that string.

Answer (score 1):

> 2147483647 (this value is for any value of k, I think it is random?)

No, it is not random; it is the largest value a signed 32-bit integer can hold.

Your inputs are too big.

When this happens, the return value of `atoi` is undefined (per [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)); the result you're seeing is common in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Define `kbits` to be one byte longer then the number of `1`s you want to store and do initialise it to all `0`s.

```
#define K (5)
char kbits[K + 1] = ""; /* One more for the `0`temrination neseccary to terminate a C-"string". */
```